# Can GSON be used to check object equality instead of overriding equals for POJO classes?

Tags: java, gson, equals, equality

I have classes such as the following (skipped getters and setters and business logic methods)

```
class Appearance{
    int heightInCm, weightInLbs;
    String eyeColor, hairColor, skinColor;
}

class Address {
    String street, apt, city, country;
    int zipCode;
}

class Person {
    String firstName, LastName, middleInitials;
    Appearance appearance;
    Address address;
}
```

I want to be able to compare objects of types above. They also have methods, some static final constants that I have skipped. Can I overriding `equals` method as follows?

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String o1 = gson.toJson(this);
    String o2 = gson.toJson((cast)o);
    return o1.equals(o2);
}
```

I know this is lazy but I am trying to quickly prototype some apps and this would save me a lot of time. I don't care about performance, just the correctness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as your classes are POJOs, yes this will work. However, the cast you're doing might cause a ClassCastException if the type you're providing to the `equals` method is not the same as the type of `this`. It will also throw an exception if `null` is sent.

Just so you know, you can also auto-generate the `equals` method in most IDEs. For instance, in Eclipse, you can generate that method by doing this:

> Right-Click on a class in the Package Explorer > "Source" > "Generate hashCode() and equals()" > Check the fields that should be checked for equality > "OK"

I can't really speak about Intellij Idea since I'm not using it, but [this link](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/generate-equals-and-hashcode-wizard.html) might help you.

I believe it better and much safer to do it this way, as it checks for `null` values and checks the type before casting. You can also chose which values should be checked for equality, which can be useful if you want to skip some `final` values.

Comment: Agreed. Plus, I don't think GSON assures properties ordering, which may be an issue if something goes haywire between the two conversions (optimization, maybe?).

Comment: I didn't know eclipse had code generator for equals. I also found code generator for toString(). That will save me a lot of time.

Comment: You can also generate getters / setters using `Right-click on a class in the Package Explorer > "Source" > "Generate Getters and Setters" > Check the fields you want to generate the getters / setters > "OK"`